# Compare two groups with differnt treatments and different populations

Tags: group-differences, treatment-effect, confounding, baseline

I will simplify my research question. I have 40 patients (group 1) with assessed a variable v1  (e.g. their blood preassure) at timepoint 0 ( v1(t0) ). After treatment (treatment 1 at timepoint 1) I measure the same variable v1(t1). A second group (group 2) is treated with different treatment and v1 were assessed at to and t1. Primarily I'm interested in difference in treatment effects (v1(t1, group 1) vs. v1(t1, group 2)). However, the mean age difference between the patients in the two groups was 10 years. Thus, they were already different (v1(t0, group 1) = 1.5 x v1(t0, group 2) before treatment. What would be the appropriate stat. analysis to investigate for effect differences of two treatments between the two groups (v1(t1, group 1) vs. (v1(t1, group 2)), but considering the age? Also, age will affect some other biological markers (e.g. the hear rate) (that were assessed as well). Is this something that I could/should include in the analysis?
I'm aware, that I could simply calculate the effet in each group using (v1(t1) - v1(t0)). However, initially, the groups were supposed to be homogenous (no age difference), so a simple unpaired test could be performed (v1(t1, group1) vs (v1(t1, group 2)) and this was not the case (due to bad luck).

Comment: Is there a plausible mechanism where the treatment effect of the drug depends on age?

Comment: This seems like a difference-in-differences analysis scenario. [Here](https://doi.org/10.1111/1475-6773.13666) is some info in adjusting for covariates in diff-in-diff.

Comment: @dimitriy: yes, that's something I know and expect.